# Merge Duplicate Contacts

Tags: icloud, high-sierra, contacts

I have noticed that most of my Contacts appear to be duplicated when I list `All Contacts` on my Mac. This is a nuisance in email.

I was checking and when I look at `All iCloud` I have 221 Contacts.

When I look at `All iCloud` I have 221 Contacts.

When I look at `All Contacts` I have 409 Contacts.

Further investigation shows that a few, which only appear once, have a `cards` attribute with `On My Mac` and `iCloud`.

How can I merge these duplicates. The `Card` `Look for Duplicates` finds none.

If I manually select a pair duplicates I can `Link Selected Cards` but it appears I would need to repeat this ~200 times.

Is there a simpler way to automate the process?

---

### EDIT

The Contacts are synched through iCloud to my phone and iPad, and there are no duplicates.

Most of these originated on a Windows XP machine, and "transferred" via a variety of tools to a MacBook in 2011. Since then they have been through a variety of steps, as apple introduced iCloud, and I changed AppleID and moved between computers.

I fundamentally mistrust cloud storage (indeed in much of Australia there is no internet access), but there is probably no need to keep a copy `On My Mac`, so the simplest solution to my problem may be to just delete all `On My Mac` and use iCloud.

Comment: Very long shot & it doesn't feel like a dupe, but just maybe https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/183141/two-identical-icloud-group-lists-in-contacts would be worth a look at

Comment: @Tetsujin I did have 2 aliases - deleted one, but didn't help.

Comment: If you have a google account you might want to import the contacts into google contacts. The duplicate detection there is way better than what Apple offers.

Comment: If you got an iPhone: If you move it all to iCloud, you can find a lot of duplicate finder apps on the iOS AppStore